# Detecting when a series of characters repeats itself in better than O(n!)

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to find when a series of characters (it's actually a really long number) begins to repeat itself. I figured that a pattern would be easiest. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The easiest way is to bruteforce it but then your run time is O(n!)

Comment: Yeah its wayy too long to brute force  :) I tried

Comment: Something similar may have been asked.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29

Comment: thanks for the repsonse. How do I use that method? I don't know much about patterns in java

Comment: This is an ambiguous question: What exactly do you mean by repeat itself? Where are you looking for the repeat to happen? (I.e. what is the haystack?). Please give examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a number, start at the end.

Find the sequence for which the last `n` and the second last `n` digit are the same which is repeated over the largest number of digits. O(n)

Where the repeated sequence stops (coming from the end) that is where the repeating starts.

e.g. say you have 1.2340111101111

You can see `1` repeats, but only for 4 digits. `01111` repeats for 10 digits meaning the repeating starts after `1.234`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where this sequence is coming from, [this might be useful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java. I'm not sure of your exact question but it seems like you are trying to find the maximal orbit of a sequence. The following pseudocode should help:

```
Given sequence M of length N
Initialize list of indices K
foreach index i from N-1 to N/2
    seqLength := N-i
    isOrbit? := true
    foreach index s from 0 to seqLength-1
        if M[N-1-s] != M[N-1-seqLength-s] then
            isOrbit? := false
    if isOrbit? then
       append(K, i)
```

The longest orbit is, of course, the last entry added to K. The algorithm is O(n^2/4) or so. It is, essentially, a modified subsequence-search algorithm.

Comment: @Ethan, this may not be nerd-exchange, but he gets an upvote from me for providing good search fodder for the asker.